# How does Visual Studio Code (VSCode) recommend extensions to install based on the current workspace?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

VSCode recommends language and related extensions, such as the C# extension, based on the files currently loaded and/or edited.

It seems to have a pretty psychic understanding of my needs, so I got curious about how these recommendations work.

Is this something an extension can influence dynamically (perhaps in its manifest up in the cloud), or are there just a static set of rules (such as file type) that VSCode uses to match up against potential extensions?

I took a look at the [Extension API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api) but could not find any information about this.

Answer (score 3):

There is a section about recommended extensions in the [Visual Studio Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_recommended-extensions)

It also says some stuff about altering the recommendations and such stuff.

UPDATE:

Maybe answers the part of your question about altering the recommendations (from the documentation):

> Workspace recommended extensions

> A good set of extensions can make
> working with a particular workspace or programming language more
> productive and you'd often like to share this list with your team or
> colleagues. You can create a recommended list of extensions for a
> workspace with the Extensions: Configure Recommended Extensions
> (Workspace) command.
>
> In a single folder workspace, the command creates an extensions.json
> file located in the workspace .vscode folder where you can add a list
> of extensions identifiers ({publisherName}.{extensionName}).
>
> In a multi-root workspace, the command will open your .code-workspace
> file where you can list extensions under extensions.recommendations.
> You can still add extension recommendations to individual folders in a
> multi-root workspace by using the Extensions: Configure Recommended
> Extensions (Workspace Folder) command.
>
> An example extensions.json could be:
>
> ```json
> {   
>   "recommendations": [ 
>     "ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-tslint-plugin",
>     "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint",
>     "msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome"
>   ]
> }
> ```
>
> which recommends two linter extensions, TSLint and ESLint, as well as the Chrome debugger
> extension.

Comment: Thanks. I took a look but not sure if it answers the question - that section is about extensions that other users recommend for you (if I understand it correctly.) Could you quote the text that answers my question specifically, to help me and other readers that arrive here?

Comment: The text you quote says "You can create a recommended list of extensions..." which means that it refers to recommendations by users. What I'm asking about is automatic recommendations made by VSCode itself, without any user involvement.

Comment: Here's an article for doing it with multi-root workspaces: https://www.bockensm.com/2021/03/06/vs-code-workspace-recommended-extensions/

Comment: You have to add a separate json property to the root object:   "extensions": {
    "recommendations": [
      "editorconfig.editorconfig"
    ]
  }